# Latitude and Longitude, 2 indexes or 1 composite index?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm curious what the most efficient way to index this would be in the context of, for instance, a map-based store locator.

1. The user pans/zooms the map to the region they would like to view.
2. The application determines the bounds of the viewport, aka max/min for lat/lng.

A query is issued in the basic form:

```
SELECT *
FROM locations
WHERE lat BETWEEN $min_lat AND $max_lat
    AND lng BETWEEN $min_lng AND $max_lng
```

Is it best to use a single composite `INDEX(lat, lng)`, or two separate indexes like `INDEX(lat), INDEX(lng)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `lat` and `lng` are independant from each other and you are using them in your `where`  clause seperately and not combined I would go for seperate indexes.

Comment: Your answer got things clearing up in my mind, and then I came across [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index) which tied everything up for me nicely. Thanks!