# MySQL multiple unique keys, drawback

Tags: mysql

Is there a drawback to crate a unique key containing fields A, B, C and then create another one with fields C, B, A, so MySQL will take advantage of the index in case of searching only with A and only with C?

Comment: More memory or disk space used...

Comment: @BrianRoach: I am just a beginner, but accoding to MySQL docs, it will help, I think... or not?

Comment: Actually, I forgot with mySQL you get a benefit on leftmost. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1823818/302916. That said ... if you're never going to use the composite key, why waste the space? You need to figure out what your use patterns are and index accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to create an additional composite `UNIQUE` constraint. The case when you access your data by only `A` is already covered by existing index `(a, b, c)`.  If you need to support queries with access path only by `c` then you can create an index just on `c`.

If your schema looks something like

```
mysql> create table tablex 
    -> (
    ->   a int not null, 
    ->   b int not null, 
    ->   c int not null
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into tablex values (1, 2, 3),(2, 3, 4),(1, 3, 3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> create unique index idx_abc_unique on tablex (a, b, c);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

If you filter on `A` only you'll see that unique index is properly used because `A` is the leftmost prefix (`keylen = 4`) of the index. `Extra` column in `EXPLAIN` results shows `Using index`.

```
mysql> explain select * from tablex where a = 1;
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablex | ref  | idx_abc_unique | idx_abc_unique | 4       | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------+----------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now if you try filter on `C` then you'll see a different story. `EXPLAIN` shows that MySQL is in fact using unique index but is doing full index scan (`type = index`) with a filter predicate identified by `Using where` in `Extra` column.

```
mysql> explain select * from tablex where c = 3;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablex | index | NULL          | idx_abc_unique | 12      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a2d5/1)** demo

If we create an explicit index on `C`

```
mysql> create index idx_c on tablex (c);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

and take a look at `EXPLAIN` we'll see again `Using index`.

```
mysql> explain select * from tablex where c = 3;
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tablex | ref  | idx_c         | idx_c | 4       | const |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+-------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a2d5/1)** demo