# MySQL adding join slows down whole query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, innodb

```
SELECT journey.code, journey.departure, journey.end, group_concat(pattern_road.latitude)
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
LEFT JOIN pattern_road ON pattern_road.section = pattern.section
WHERE journey_day.day = 5 AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN journey.departure AND journey.end
GROUP BY journey.code
```

The above query takes roughly 100ms to execute. I am happy with this, but I now need to add another join, when I try to do this the query slows down to roughly 2 seconds.

This is the new slow query with the extra join:

```
SELECT journey.code, journey.departure, journey.end, group_concat(pattern_road.latitude) AS road, group_concat(link.stop) AS stop
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
LEFT JOIN pattern_road ON pattern_road.section = pattern.section
INNER JOIN link ON link.section = pattern.section
WHERE journey_day.day = 5 AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN journey.departure AND journey.end
GROUP BY journey.code
```

Things to note:

The extra join also operates on the same column as the previous join (pattern_road) joins on, I can only think that this must be the cause of the problem. For example, if I replace pattern_road join with the link join, the query is back to 100ms, I just can't use both joins and have it run at 100ms.

[Database schematic/indexes in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc6bee)

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to index link on column section

Comment: @Jasen I already have that index in place. I have linked an SQL Fiddle in the question so that you can see existing indexes and table structure.

Comment: performance tests are impossible without data, maybe you could be running out of memory o

Comment: To my way of thinking, there is almost no problem for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution - especially so when it's the only aggregating function in the query. Why not omit it altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way?

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE journey.code, journey.departure, journey.end,
  (select group_concat(pattern_road.latitude) from  pattern_road where pattern_road.section = pattern.section) AS road,
  (select group_concat(link.stop) from link where link.section = pattern.section) AS stop
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.code
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.code = journey.pattern
WHERE journey_day.day = 5 AND TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN journey.departure AND journey.end
GROUP BY journey.code
```

Comment: Much better!! Thanks so much. That reduces the query back to down to 100ms. Just for reference, in the query you missed the `left join pattern_road` but referenced it in `select` in the answer, if I add that on it works perfectly :)

Comment: Oh, 1 moment, maybe you don't need to add anything... just need to check the query again

Comment: Oddly your query takes 6 seconds to run. However, if I add a left join like so: `LEFT JOIN pattern_road ON pattern_road.section = pattern.section` after the pattern join, it takes 100ms! No idea why this is happening

Comment: Can you try to add SQL_NO_CACHE after the select and before the rows?

Comment: Could you edit your question and put SQL_NO_CACHE in it? Not quite sure where to put it

Comment: No change with `SQL_NO_CACHE` added on

Comment: The SQL_NO_CACHE should only turn off query caching which should make the comparison better. Without it if you run the same query 2 times, the second one can be much quicker if there wasn't any modification in the related tables between the 2 execution.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that two indexes on two columns are not the same as one [composite index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823751/1446005) on two columns. A query can only use one index per table<sup>*</sup>.

Add an index on `pattern(code, section)` or `pattern(section, code)` (a live test with the actual data is required to find out which one provides better result).

---

<sup>*</sup> *except in [very rare cases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html)*