# Database design - children of join tables key choice

Tags: sql, foreign-key-relationship, surrogate-key

**I searched for answers to the following, but got answers mostly related to whether or not to use a surrogate at all, not about whether or not to then use compound keys on children of join tables.**

I have a table `attendees` and a table `events`.

The join table is `event_attendees`, containing two foreign keys `attendee_id` and `event_id`, and also has a surrogate primary key `id`

let's now say attendees in an event can have `schedule_items`.

I would normally simply use the columns `event_attendee_id`, `schedule_item_id` in the table `event_attendee_schedule_items`.

What drawbacks, if any, would using the following compound foreign key set up have over the above?

`attendee_id`, `event_id`, `schedule_item_id` (compound key instead of a direct link to the `event_attendees` table)?

Comment: The second solution, using the coumpound key, sounds more logical to me. As you have one person at one place at one time... You're linking three tables together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the first approach if:

- the table `event_attendees` is still required. Because if you have two join tables `event_attendees` and `event_attendee_schedule_items` (which is basically what you get if you use the second approach) you can enter inconsistent data. Even if you can guarantee that the two tables are in sync (for example by the external program which is writing the data in), I wouldn't to this.
- you have ideas of other extensions in the same style, like a table `event_attendee_invoice_parts` (which would link to invoice data) you can put common data into `event_attendees`
- `event_attendees` has its own properties like `entry_badge_id` which will be used in the context of `event_attendee_schedule_items`. For this queries, you have to join with `event_attendees` anyways.

The last reason gives us an additional hint: *it depends on amount of data in the tables and the queries you make!* In some cases your performance will benefit from composite keys (and composite *indexes*), in other cases not. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I've used the pattern you described as best before, and it worked well.

The big difference, and a good point I didn't think of was the idea of storing common data on that event_attendees table.

Thanks for the reply.