# What is the most efficient way to deal with triple (n to n to n) relation's table?

Tags: mysql, sql

## Entities:

- Users
- Hotels
- Roles

## Relations:

When Users are assigned to a Hotel they are also assigned one or more Roles.

## Example:

Alice (USER) can be assigned to Blue Moon Hotel (HOTEL) as Head Manager (ROLE). And also can be assigned to Rainbow Hotel (HOTEL) as a Marketing Manager (ROLE) AND a Reservation Manager (ROLE).

## Problem

Hotels and Users tables will the biggest ones in the DB and they will be joined very frequently. We fear that the join operations will be too costly if we insert 2 rows for Alice and Rainbow Hotel (one for marketing manager and one for reservation manager). Considering the complexity is U^2 x H^2 x R^2 we might face some problems in the long run.

## Current Approach:

[image: Approach]

Comment: What is your approach ? I can't see images.

Comment: @Cid Have a relation table with userId, HotelId and RoleId (having multiple rows if the user has 2 roles for the same hotel)

Comment: What's wrong with it ?

Comment: You certainly need to create the right indexes to make queries efficient. To get advice on query optimization, you should show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table, and also show the SQL query you want to optimize.

Comment: @Cid In the long run we may face problems with the complexity of the query joining the 3 tables as hotels and users will be the tables with the biggest quantity of rows.

Comment: *"Considering the complexity is U^2 x H^2 x R^2"*: could you explain how you arrive to that?

Comment: You want indexes on your search criterias. This will increases the disk cost, but will greatly decrease the query execution time.

Comment: @trincot Worst case: every user is assigned to every hotel with every Role. U x H x R x UHR = U^2 x H^2 x R^2

Comment: Will look into it @Cid

Comment: I also considered having a String field instead of roleId. having all ids separated by a comma on that field. So we have only one row per USER-HOTEL. We could get the Roles on another query after that.

Comment: Indexed fields use binary searches. it takes log2(n) checks before finding out that the requested search criteria doesn't match. For a 7 billions entries tables, this is 33 checks.

Comment: *"having all ids separated by a comma on that field"* This is a **very bad idea**

Comment: @Cid So there won't be any problem with my original approach?

Comment: You can use composite indexes instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index)

Comment: @J.Nicastro no problem, as long as you have enough disk space

Comment: It will never be U x H x R x UHR. Even if you select all related records, then you first select all records from the UHR-table and then with the indexes on primary keys of the base tables you just get the corresponding (unique) records from the U, H and R tables. So that is UHR + UHR.

Comment: @Cid that's exactly what I needed! Composite Indexes will do.   Post it as an Answer if you want! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't want to plagiate an answer

Comment: @Cid Done. Thanks for your time!