# Query indices: Single column index vs Composite index: Which one is good practice and also give faster performance

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-indexes

Suppose I have table t1(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5,..)

I need to run queries where the columns (e.g. c1, c2, c3 here) used in where condition of select query as in below. The queries are making application slow.

- `select * from t1 where c1=somevalue1 and c2=somevalue2`
- `select * from t1 where c3=somevalue1`
- `select * from t1 where c1=somevalue1 and c2=somevalue2 and c3=somevalue`

To improve performance of the queries, I want to create index on the columns which are used on where clause. what should be a better approach to create index on columns(c1, c2, c3)?
multiple indexes like index1(c1), index2(c2), index3(c3), index4(c1, c2, c3)
or
Just one index like index1(c1, c2, c3)

Can anybody please advise on this??

Comment: Have you tried testing various approaches. ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a composite index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823685/when-should-i-use-a-composite-index)

Comment: Does the table have a Primary Key?

Comment: Mandatory read regarding indexes in relational databases: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: yes wildplasser, it has primery key

Comment: thanks Benjamin and All, it helped to clear my doubts about usage of composite index

Answer (score 0):

If the `WHERE` condition contains an arbitrary combinations of conditions on `c1`, `c2` and `c3`, you are probably best off creating three single-column indexes on these three columns.

PostgreSQL can combine two index scans using a `BitmapAnd` if no single condition is selective enough, but the combination is.